# compare 2 structs and extract the changes Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

There are 2 structs, one is Camera, and other one is changeset changes, I am looking for a way to save old and new values from 2 structs, for example there is

```
%Camera{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "cameras">, access_rights: [],
 alert_emails: nil, cloud_recordings: nil,
 config: %{"external_host" => "46.126.223.13", "external_http_port" => "81",
   "snapshots" => %{"audio" => "", "h264" => "axis-media/media.amp",
     "jpg" => "axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi", "mjpg" => "axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi",
     "mpeg" => ""}}, created_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2017-03-09 06:27:47>,
 discoverable: false, exid: "aarga-buezp", id: 12361, is_online: true,
 is_online_email_owner_notification: false, is_public: false,
 last_online_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2017-05-15 07:28:49>,
 last_polled_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2017-06-15 07:40:09>, location: nil,
 mac_address: nil, model_id: 4, motion_detections: nil,
 name: " Aargau Obersiggenthal", timezone: "UTC"}
```

And then there is camera's changeset

```
%{config: %{"auth" => %{"basic" => %{"password" => "", "username" => ""}},
    "external_host" => "46.126.223.13", "external_http_port" => "81",
    "external_rtsp_port" => "",
    "snapshots" => %{"audio" => "", "h264" => "axis-media/media.amp",
      "jpg" => "axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi", "mjpg" => "axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi",
      "mpeg" => ""}}, timezone: "Atlantic/Cape_Verde"}
```

There is only one value, timezone is being updated at the moment, I am looking for a way to check all collect all the new and old values from both the struct, as I have few keys in changeset, I want to compare all those key values to the old struct to see what I changed and then get a struct of only those values which have been changed, something like this

```
%{settings: %{old: old_values, new: new_values}}
```

Is there any possibility to get this done with Ecto? by itself? or is there any method to Elixir to compare two structs to see what are the changes?

UPADTE:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
 changes: %{config: %{"auth" => %{"basic" => %{"password" => "",
         "username" => ""}}, "external_host" => "46.126.223.13",
     "external_http_port" => "81", "external_rtsp_port" => "",
     "snapshots" => %{"audio" => "", "h264" => "axis-media/media.amp",
       "jpg" => "axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi", "mjpg" => "axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi",
       "mpeg" => ""}}, timezone: "Atlantic/Cape_Verde"}, errors: [],
 data: #Camera<>, valid?: true>
```

The first part the already present object, and the 2nd part are the values coming from a `form` when user trying to update the first object, so What I want here is to create a new map/struct or I really dont know what we call it to just save that object in DB,
1: Compare the changeset values to the first object, If there are few values which are new in changeset then create a new map or stuct with them with old and new sub key.

Comment: That second snippet is just a plain map, not a changeset. What is the exact input and output you're looking for? The second map does is missing multiple fields which are present in the first one and your expected output has a key `settings` which isn't present anywhere.

Comment: my only concers are to compare both new and old values to create a new object, which will have all updated values and against it the old ones as well, I dont really know about who to compare or loop between objects like that

Comment: @Dogbert can you assist sir?

Comment: Sorry I still don't know what output you want for the input values you have shown.

Comment: Sir I want make a new object with old values and new values, with same KEYs `%{settings: %{old: %{timezone: UTC}, new: %{timezone: Dublin}}}`